# Add custom points to a shape that has been converted to a path without disfiguring the svg/path

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I have a custom shape that i've just given converted to a path and then i click on the nodes tool and see the following :-

[image]

Now what i'd like to do is delete these nodes and add custom nodes at certain points , I know how to add custom nodes but when i delete an existing node i see disfiguration, like below :-

[image]

so how do i delete a node without disfiguration ? Also , have tried `join/merge nodes` with the same result. How do i go about deleting nodes without having the path/svg messed up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, some software do it better but essentially your asking for 270 degree arc created with a a single Bezier span. This is not going to work. Essentially anything over 180 degree, is way off, 180 may under some circumstances acceptable but 90 seems to be ok for most uses, and 60 or 45 if you need to have any sort of real accuracy.

So I am afraid that the configuration you have chosen wouldn't work in any case. The software is really doing the best it can under the circumstances and in my opinion is doing okay.

Comment: alright , have another question though if possible for you to answer. How do i know the direction of the path and the starting point of the path ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik its in the direction of the handle